# Selecting elements and inserting them into List of tables in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to insert the selected value of columns into List of Tables, Here is my code:

First I've Created an Object:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE ordersinf as OBJECT(orderDate DATE, orderName VARCHAR2(20), orderPrice NUMBER)
```

Then

```
CREATE OR REPLACE orders_tab IS TABLE OF ordersinf
```

and Finally my Function:

```
create or replace function execImmFunc(orderName in VARCHAR2, orderPrice in NUMBER) return orders_tab is
  Result orders_tab := orders_tab();
  myName orders_table.orders_name%type;
  myPrice orders_table.orders_price%type;
begin

  RESULT.extend();

  SELECT orders_name, orders_price
  **INTO RESULT(1).ordersInf('NULL',orders_name, orders_price)**
  --I'm Having trouble with the above code.. 
  FROM orders_table
  WHERE orders_name = orderName AND orders_price = orderPrice;

  --result.extend();
  --result(result.last) := ordersinf(NULL,orderName, orderPrice);
  return(Result);
end execImmFunc;
```

How Can I accomplish this? I'm sorry if this is a dumb question but I'm very new into this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `BULK COLLECT` to retrieve data:

```
create or replace function execImmFunc(orderName in VARCHAR2, orderPrice in NUMBER) 
  return orders_tab is

  Result orders_tab := orders_tab();

begin
  SELECT ordersinf(null, orders_name, orders_price)
    bulk collect INTO RESULT
    FROM orders_table
    WHERE orders_name = orderName AND orders_price = orderPrice;
  return(Result);
end execImmFunc;
```

Test:

```
create or replace type ordersinf 
  as object(orderdate date, ordername varchar2(20), orderprice number);
create or replace type orders_tab is table of ordersinf;
create table orders_table (orders_name varchar2(20), orders_price number);
insert into orders_table values ('ORD1', 101);
insert into orders_table values ('ORD2', 102);
insert into orders_table values ('ORD3', 103);

select * from table(execImmFunc('ORD1', 101))
```

Output:

```
ORDERDATE   ORDERNAME            ORDERPRICE
----------- -------------------- ----------
            ORD1                        101
```

Comment: Thanks! Your help is much appreciated sir! =)

Answer (score 2):

> Hey just an alternative approach can be implemented by using PIPELINED
>   function as mentioned below. Hope it also helps

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE ordersinf
AS
  OBJECT
  (
    orderDate  DATE,
    orderName  VARCHAR2(20 CHAR),
    orderPrice NUMBER);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE orders_tab IS TABLE OF ordersinf;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION execImmFunc(
    orderName  IN VARCHAR2,
    orderPrice IN NUMBER)
  RETURN orders_tab pipelined
IS
  Rsult orders_tab := orders_tab();
  myName orders_table.orders_name%type;
  myPrice orders_table.orders_price%type;
BEGIN
  SELECT NULL,
    orders_name,
    orders_price BULK COLLECT
  INTO Rsult
  FROM orders_table
  WHERE orders_name = orderName
  AND orders_price  = orderPrice;
  FOR i IN Rsult.FIRST..Rsult.LAST
  LOOP
    PIPE ROW(I);
  END LOOP;
  RETURN ;
END execImmFunc;
```

Comment: Good point @AvrajitRoy. Variable declarations for `myName`, `myPrice` are unnecessary.

Comment: @Ponder: yes i forgot to remove that. My bad :)